# Помогите мне ребята исправить ошибки - not a function. что я не так делаю?

Tags: javascript

```js
var salaryCalculator = function (baseSalary) {
  this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
  this.calculateSalary = function (profession) {
    if (profession === "mechanic") {
      var multiplier = 1.8;
    } else if (profession === "developer") {
      var multiplier = 2.8;
    } else if (profession === "doctor") {
      var multiplier = 3.2;
    } else if (profession === "professor") {
      var multiplier = 4.1;
    } else {
      return this.baseSalary * multiplier;
    }
  }
}

var salaryCalculator1 = new salaryCalculator(800);

var salary = salaryCalculator.calculateSalary("mechanic");
var salary = salaryCalculator.calculateSalary("developer");
var salary = salaryCalculator.calculateSalary("doctor");
var salary = salaryCalculator.calculateSalary("professor");

console.log(salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Septinta pamoka</title>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Что за ошибка и где она возникает?

Answer (score 1):

Уверен, что твой код сейчас ничего не делает, т.к. ты только объявляешь переменные. Но ошибка ясна:

```
var salaryCalculator1 = new salaryCalculator(800);
```

Тут ты объявил переменную `salaryCalculator1`, но дальше используешь название функции, которая не имеет статичных методов:

```
var salary = salaryCalculator.calculateSalary("mechanic");
```

Что и выдает ошибку. правильный код:

```
var salaryCalculator = function (baseSalary) {
  this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
  this.calculateSalary = function (profession) {
    if (profession === "mechanic") {
      var multiplier = 1.8;
    } else if (profession === "developer") {
      var multiplier = 2.8;
    } else if (profession === "doctor") {
      var multiplier = 3.2;
    } else if (profession === "professor") {
      var multiplier = 4.1;
    } else {
      return this.baseSalary * multiplier;
    }
  }
}

var salaryCalculator1 = new salaryCalculator(800);

var salary = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("mechanic");
var salary = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("developer");
var salary = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("doctor");
var salary = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("professor");

console.log(salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary());
```

Answer (score 1):

salaryCalculator - это конструктор класса, ошибку вызывает попытка использовать метод класса (а не метод объекта класса).

кроме того,

`return this.baseSalary * multiplier;` для правильных зарплат не будет вызвано из-за нахождения в else

`console.log(salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary());` не содержит в вызове функции обязательного параметра

и 4 раза объявляется одна и та же переменная..

```js
var salaryCalculator = function (baseSalary) {
  this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
  this.calculateSalary = function (profession) {
    var multiplier;
    if (profession === "mechanic") {
      multiplier = 1.8;
    } else if (profession === "developer") {
      multiplier = 2.8;
    } else if (profession === "doctor") {
      multiplier = 3.2;
    } else if (profession === "professor") {
      multiplier = 4.1;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Такой профессии нет");
    }
    return this.baseSalary * multiplier;
  }
}

var salaryCalculator1 = new salaryCalculator(800);

var salary1 = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("mechanic");
var salary2 = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("developer");
var salary3 = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("doctor");
var salary4 = salaryCalculator1.calculateSalary("professor");

console.log([salary1,salary2,salary3,salary4]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Septinta pamoka</title>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```